# Accessing All Business Unit Calendars from a child business unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, calendar

We have multiple business units and want to be able to provide a way for users in any business unit to access and view any other business units email calendar.

I looked through the roles and couldn't find any privilege to turn on.  Myself as a super admin can be in any business unit and be able to access any calendar.

Is it possible?